# Unable to move Mouse VirtualBox Snow Leopard Server Install

Tags: macos, mouse

I am trying to install Snow Leopard Server in a virtual machine, but I can't seem to get the mouse to work properly.

Comment: Snow Leopard Client or Snow Leopard Server?

Comment: @user3439894 Client

Comment: Snow Leopard Client version is not virtualizable by its SLA.

Comment: @user3439894 Even on Mac OSX because the cd boots fine.

Comment: Snow Leopard Server version is virtualizable on Apple-branded hardware by its SLA.  Clients versions of OS X prior to OS X Lion are not virtualizable by the SLA.

Comment: @user3439894 - 10.6 client *is* virtualizable in spite of the SLA, VirtualBox supports the creation of 10.6 virtual machines - albeit with some fairly major performance and stability limitations - hence **William**'s original post...

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly I know it technically doable however doing so is in violation of its SLA and therefore I was under the impression it was not open for discussion in this forum.

Comment: @user3439894 I doubt apple cares at all.  There are a lot of questions that are in one gray area or another.

Comment: @William, according to "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" It says... "Please refrain from asking about the following topics...", "Installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware (and most other explicitly unlicensed use of product)".  Note the part in parentheses and that part is independent of doing it on non-Apple hardware.  So I'd say there is no gray area there as it violates the SLA and therefore not allowed here.

Comment: @user3439894 fixed

Comment: I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard Server running without any mouse issues in VMware Fusion, so you might want to give it a try.  It does have a free 30 day fully functional trial license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exit out of the keyboard pop up and let the mouse pop up display you can successfully control the mouse after the boot screen appears.